# How to refer derived class in template member?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, member

The code below won't compile:

```
struct Base
{
    std::vector<void(Base::*)(void)> x;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    void foo() {}
};

// ...

Derived d;
d.x.push_back(&Derived::foo);
```

Is it possible to refer derived class in template member `x`? In the example above I specify exactly `Base` and derived classes cannot push their own member functions into vector `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting is bad since your code have to assume that this will be called only for instance of `Derived` class. This means that you either have to assume that all items in `x` are instance of `Derived` (in such case declaration of `x` is to general and should be changed to `std::vector<void(Derived::*)(void)> x;`) or you have to maintain extra information what which class method is stored in specific position of `x`. Both approaches are bad.

In modern C++ it is much better do do it like this:

```
struct Base
{
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> x;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    void foo() {}
};

// ...

Derived d;
d.x.push_back([&d](){ d.foo(); });
```

Another good approach can be CRTP:

```
template<class T>
struct Base
{
    std::vector<void(T::*)(void)> x;
};

struct Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    void foo() {}
};

// ...

Derived d;
d.x.push_back(&Derived::foo);
```

Comment: I see, cool. It it possible to avoid lamba here? For example there are bound methods in python. Is it possible to store pointers to methods already bound to some objects as ordinary functions?

Comment: @Leonid that's what the lambda is doing. Note that it captures a reference to `d`

Comment: Does lambda approach add overhead? Is class template approach better in this sense?

Comment: The template approach is potentially less overhead. You will have to cast to `T` if you want to call the members in a method of `Base`

Answer (score 0):

You may, but there is no implicit conversion; it requires a cast.

```
Derived d;
d.x.push_back(static_cast<void(Base::*)()>(&Derived::foo));
```

The caveat is the if you use that pointer to member with an object that isn't really a `Derived`, the behavior is undefined. Tread carefully.

---

As an addendum, if you want to get rid of the cast when taking the pointer, you can do that by encapsulating the push (with some static type checking to boot):

```
struct Base
{
    std::vector<void(Base::*)(void)> x;

    template<class D>
    auto push_member(void (D::* p)()) -> 
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Base, D>::value> {
        x.push_back(static_cast<void(Base::*)()>(p));
    }
};
```

Comment: so there is no possibility to make a template member "virtual"?

Comment: @Leonid - I'm not sure what you mean. What's "virtual"?

Comment: I mean that it could behave like virtual method. On base class the template is parameterized with the base class, on a derived class it is parameterized with derived class..

Comment: @Leonid - What template? The type of `x` is concrete. It's an instantiation of `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would express this by calling through a non-virtual member function on the base.

example:

```
#include <vector>

struct Base
{
    std::vector<void(Base::*)(void)> x;

    // public non-virtual interface    
    void perform_foo()
    {
        foo();
    }

private:
    // private virtual interface for the implementation
    virtual void foo() = 0;    
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
private:
    // override private virtual interface
    void foo() override {}

};

// ...

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.x.push_back(&Base::perform_foo);

    auto call_them = [](Base& b)
    {
        for (auto&& item : b.x)
        {
            (b.*item)();
        }
    };

    call_them(d);
}
```